# Why does my program throw an "IndexOutOfBoundsException", with Index: 1, Size: 0

Tags: java

I am making an initiative tracker for D&D in Java, consisting of an Arraylist which is populated by random integers. However, when i try to read a given index of the ArrayList, the program throws an exception:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Add number of enemies");

        int a = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> initiativeList = new ArrayList<>(a); // This is where i have added it, code was not updated.

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) { // adding a given number to Arraylist
            int initRoll = rand.nextInt(19);
            initiativeList.add(i, initRoll);
            System.out.println(initRoll);
        }
        int q = initiativeList.get(3);
        System.out.println(q);


    }
}
```

I have set the size of the ArrayList to be equal to int a, which takes user input.

Comment: "I have set the size of the ArrayList to be equal to int a, which takes user input." <- No you didn't and you can't because ArrayList doesn't have a fixed size.

Comment: `I have set the size of the ArrayList to be equal to int a` Where do you see that in your code?

Comment: ArrayList doesn't need to you set the index if you only add to the end of the list

Comment: Indices in java start from 0 upto size - 1. Here you can simply add to the end `initiativeList.add(initRoll);`

Comment: Why are you using an ArrayList rather than an int[]?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add initRoll at index 1 when your ArrayList only has index 0 yet at line

```
initiativeList.add(i, initRoll);
```

To fix that change `for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

"Why does my program throw an “IndexOutOfBoundsException”, with Index: 1, Size: 0". Pretty self explanatory isn't it? Then index is 1 and the size of the collection is 0, therefore,  your index is out of bounds....

Answer (score 0):

What you pass, when calling the `ArrayList`'s constructur is the initial capacity, not the actual size or number of elements. The `ArrayList` does not have a fixed size. (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int))

The problem occurs, when you are doing the following:

```java
initiativeList.add(i, initRoll);
```

You iterate with `i=1` and try to insert into the `ArrayList` at position `1`. The list is empty at that point, so there is no position `1`. You could insert as follows:

```java
initiativeList.add(i-1, initRoll);
```

or add without the first parameter, which will append to the list.

Next problem will occur, when you enter a number less than `4` because your list will not have an element with index `3`.

```java
# Will break, when entering a number less than 4
int q = initiativeList.get(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the size of the array list with its capacity:

- the size is the number of elements in the list;
- the capacity is how many elements the list can potentially accommodate without reallocating its internal structures.

Below initialization shows arraylist capacity(how many elements the list can accommodate) -

```
ArrayList<Integer> initiativeList = new ArrayList<>(a);//here  you are not setting size of list, you are setting list capacity to a.
```

Thats why your code throwing out of bound exception because its size is actually 0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the iterator initialization to zero

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
```

your error is because you trying to assign to index 1 of the list a value, while zero is not populated, either start int i = 0 or use a map.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, Java is zero indexed. Start your for loop at 0 instead of 1.